# Shadowbox inside a list

Tags: html, html-lists, image, shadowbox

I have a problem using shadowbox inside a list. The image that im trying to use with shadowbox, is inside an li tag. I have tried to implement shadowbox on an , that is outside the list, and that is working correctly.

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery" class="content-2">
        <nav id="filter"></nav>
        <section id="container">
            <ul id="stage">
                <li data-tags="Print Design"><a rel="shadowbox" href="_img/shots/1.jpg"><img src="_img/shots/1.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design,Print Design"><a rel="shadowbox" href="_img/shots/2.jpg"><img src="_img/shots/2.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a></li>
           </ul>
        </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, and judging by the limited HTML you've presented, it looks like your using [**jQuery Quicksand**](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) plugin too?

If so, check out [**Quicksand Demo featuring Shadowbox**](http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/Quicksand-Demo-featuring-Shadowbox-tp7303500.html) I made a while back which was based on this [**Online Tutorial**](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/).

Even if you weren't using Quicksand, *the idea is the same* to get Shadowbox to work as you expect: That is to run `Shadowbox.setup();` during the callback process of your *other script*.

Basically, after another script alters the DOM and changes around other elements for Shadowbox objects, Shadowbox will not cache new objects until they are manually added to Shadowbox cache via `Shadowbox.setup()`.

*Note:* You might have to first run `Shadowbox.clearCache();` in order to flush out previously catched links, otherwise your cloned objects starts to multiply.

Also, be sure to open the demo's `.js` file since that has a lot of tutorial comments I wrote, specifically for Shadowbox use.